# Htaccess RewriteRule change subdomain url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm in this situation

```
http://example.com/sub-domain/
```

and I wish to have this

```
http://example.com/sub/domain/
```

without loosing in SEO, what's the right RewriteRule?

At the moment this is my `.htaccess` file in the subdomain `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub-domain/
# exclude any paths that are not codeigniter-app related
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server-status
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/server-info
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/docs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
# the following is for rewritting under FastCGI
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT**

In my root domain I have installed Wordpress and this is the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave `/sub-domain/.htaccess` as is. And have this rule in root .htaccess (a level above `/sub-domain/`):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /sub-domain(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /sub/domain%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^sub/domain(/.*)?$ sub-domain$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks! I tried to place it before the wordpress loop in the main directory, however it doesn't work I get the 404 trying access directly. I checked the error log of apache and there are no messages

Comment: You never told anything about WP. Is WP running in root domain?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that I thought it can be done without edit the main htaccess

Comment: Is subdomain also running WP?

Comment: ok for testing try `RewriteRule ^sub/domain(/.*)?$ sub-domain$1 [L,NC,R]` in the root .htaccess just below `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: What is the URL it got redirected to and what the original URL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84300/discussion-between-simone-and-anubhava).